# windows form c++ read file.txt and fill textboxes

Tags: file, io, c++-cli

Okay, I have 5 textboxes, which I save the text of the textboxes into a .txt file using StreamWriter class.

But I'm not able to retrieve the text back into the textboxes from the .txt file, any idea how to do it?

hmm, this is how i write into the .txt file.

```
String^ writedata = textBox1->Text +";" + 
                    textBox2->Text + ";" + 
                    textBox3->Text + ";" + 
                    textBox4->Text + ";" + 
                    textBox5->Text + ";" + 
                    textBox6->Text + ";" + 
                    textBox7->Text + ";" + 
                    textBox8->Text;

StreamWriter^ SR = gcnew StreamWriter("C:\\Settings.txt");

SR->Write(writedata);

SR->Close();
```

Comment: You probably should have tagged this [c++-cli] instead of [c++]

Comment: How are you trying to read the text back that isn't working?

Comment: try   
 {    
  StreamReader* sr = new StreamReader("C:\\test1.txt"); 
         StreamReader reader= new StreamReader(textFile);
  do  
  {
      textBox1->Text=(reader->ReadLine());
  }   
  while(reader->Peek() != -1);
 }      
         
 catch (System::Exception^ e)
 { 
  textBox1->Text="error";
 }

Answer (score 0):

I think you can read the file into a string and then split this string using as terminated character symbol ';'